# mule http post json data thru httpendpoint

Tags: mule, mule-component

Using `mule` - how to post `json` data to invoke my application url and got response back. I have my `json` data like below:

```
{
    "Reservation" : {
        "reservation" : {
            "@id" : "123456789"
        },
        "arrivingDate" : "03-09-2012",
        "departureDate" : "03-15-2012",
        "guestName" : "Fred",
        "guestLastName" : "Davis",
        "hotelID" : "03",
        "room" : "1001",
        "oceanView" : "true",

    }
}
```

I want post my json data to my application `http://localhost:8080/myapplication/createreservation` through `MULE HTTP ENDPOINT` and get some application response back. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I like to say is your JSON data is not valid .. there should not be any comma at the end .. may be missing some attributes

If you want to post the Data to an external application you can follow the following example :-

```
<flow name="BestelItems" doc:name="BestelItems">
 <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
 <set-payload doc:name="Set Payload" value="{ &quot;Reservation&quot; : { &quot;reservation&quot; : { &quot;@id&quot; : &quot;123456789&quot; }, &quot;arrivingDate&quot; : &quot;03-09-2012&quot;, &quot;departureDate&quot; : &quot;03-15-2012&quot;, &quot;guestName&quot; : &quot;Fred&quot;, &quot;guestLastName&quot; : &quot;Davis&quot;, &quot;hotelID&quot; : &quot;03&quot;, &quot;room&quot; : &quot;1001&quot;, &quot;oceanView&quot; : &quot;true&quot;}}"/>
 <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST" address="ttp://localhost:8080/myapplication/createreservation" contentType="application/json" doc:name="HTTP"/>
</flow>
```

But if you want to post the JSON data to your own Mule application then you only need your flow to have Http inbound endpoint .. and you can post the data from any Rest Client or Postman ..

The data will automatically get into your Mule flow through the rest client or Postman application as below :-
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in the following way:

1. You can create a POJO with the field names same as the JSON elements
2. Create an instance of the object and enter your JSON input.
3. Then use Mule's Object to JSON transformer specifying the source Class with the POJO class.
4. Invoke the respective 2- way HTTP application using HTTP Outbound endpoint.
5. Once the response is received, add the JSON to Object transformer and use it to process further.